# Page Break Issue in pdf output

Tags: birt

I am using BIRT Designer, I am having an issue of page break when generating the report as PDF.

After generating the PDF report, What happen is since the note from the input file is too long for the description column to accommodate some of the string is being pushed down to next line or being wrap to ensure that the note fits in the description column area which cause for the trailer details to be push to the next page.

I have tried many page break options like avoid before and after for tables/grid but nothing is working.

Please find the attachment of sample pdf for getting page break issue and rptdesign file and xml file.

So Please give some suggestion to solve as soon as possible.

Thanks and Regards,
Sharath.

---

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues in the past and found these answers a long time ago.

Set the page break interval to zero and see if this works for you. The page break  before, inside and after settings should be set to Auto as setting something to avoid will always try to avoid page breaks when displaying your selection. Auto will use page breaks where necessary.

Check to see if this works for you.

You can also try entering this code in the beforeFactory section:

```
if( reportContext.getOutputFormat() == "pdf" ){
reportContext.getReportRunnable().designHandle.getDesignHandle().findElement("mytable").setProperty("pageBreakInterval", 0);
}
```

Go to the script tab and then change the name "mytable" to the name you have given your table under Properties > General > Name

[image: Example]